# Get root selector, and use it in as part of another selector - in Stylus

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent, stylus

I'm trying to figure out a small thing that's been annyoing me a little while.

I want the bottom selector in the code below to re-use the root selector, so the selector behaves like the working one above it.

```
.page
    position relative


    &__content
        scroll()
        overflow auto


    &--home // working
        .page__content
            margin 30px


    &--home // not working
        & ~/__content
            margin 30px
```

I know I could do the ~/ selector inside the __content block, but I'd rather not - if possible.

Comment: "*I know I could do the ~/ selector inside the __content block, but I'd rather not - if possible.*" - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only can use `~/`(*initial reference*) at the start of the selector but there is another way to achieve the same with *partial reference* `^[N]`:

**Stylus:**

```
.page
    position relative
    &__content
        scroll()
        overflow auto
    &--home 
       & ^[0]__content
            margin 30px
```

**Output:**

```
.page {
  position: relative;
}
.page__content {
  overflow: auto;
}
.page--home .page__content {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is the only way to do it for now. I'd love an example of a  alternative syntax for it that's more readable and self-describing :D

Comment: partial reference is very readable in my opinion, N is the nested level: `^[0] ---> first level`, `^[1] --> second level`... Negative values are counting from the end.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's as readable as the other parts of stylus for someone not that familiar with it :)

Comment: Maybe is not what you want but for simplify the syntax you can use a valiable: `root= "^[0]"` and use interpolation in the selector: `& {root}__content`